# Neutral grounding resistor connection

Tags: grounding, protection

I am only confused about the highlighted part. I searched the net for neutral grounding resistor and I got the same grounding method as shown here in the figure below.

Simply ground the neutral through a resistor just like here.

Can someone tell me if the connection of a neutral grounding resistor is different or not?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second sentence is a strong hint here.

Comment: @user_1818839 I didn't get which sentence you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The system is designed as an ungrounded system." Is an essential hint in the question. In the solution, the statement "such a system differs form that shown" seem to assume a schematic diagram symbol (resistor in a dotted box) is universally interpreted as a sensing resistor rather than a current limiting resistor. I think that is an unreliable assumption. However you need a reason to eliminate all but one answer selection and the quoted sentence in the question seems to provide that.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is C. Resistors in a neutral are a sure fire way of controlling ground faults in generators. In fact generators laminations are easily damaged by earth faults. Have a look at [www.eng-tips.com](http://www.eng-tips.com) for much discussion on this. As to the comment that the arrangement may differ if the generator is high voltage then an earthing transformer is included with a resistor on the LV side